# Веб-ссылки против локальных ссылок

Tags: php

Делаю простой сайт на PHP. У меня есть HTML код, в котором использованы ссылки вида "/css/styles.css" к примеру, а на локалке нужны ссылки без / в начале, иначе невидимо. Как мне на локальном компе смотреть как выглядит сайт с веб ссылками (со слешами) так, что бы не менять каждую ссылку сейчас и потом обратно?

Comment: настройте виртуальный хост. Проблемы исчезнут. Иначе вам придётся вместо прямого текста использовать функцию, которая будет возвращать нужный путь до файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте на локальной машине веб сервер.
Думаю идеальным вариантом для вас будет коробочная версия OpenServer, чуть посложней XAMPP.

Comment: XAMPP сложнее, вы шутите?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то у XAMPP надо добавлять виртуальные хосты ручками. Сложности в этом нет, но начинающему нужно будет разобраться что и куда прописывать. И конечно, можно еще дальше пойти, использовать Docker или VirtualBox.